# How to fetch YUV stream or bytes array using DirectX?

Tags: c#, windows, directx, webcam

Hi i am creating a sample application using DirectX.
I am following a sample application here:http://www.codeproject.com/KB/directx/directxcapture.aspx

Can anybody suggest where do we get frames???
i cant understand the sample its working but how???

when i click on Start a file is created with zero bytes
when i press Stop some bytes are written to this file.

but where do we get frames and bytes array?
I need to fetch them for conversion.

I am trying to debug but cant get.

Can anybody provide some idea or help

thanks in advance.

Comment: I have read DirectShow from various links but cannot find how to capture yuv data, any help????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got it to work

now i am able to obtain yuv data and store the contents in an avi file.

I followed this:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/directx/directxcapture.aspx

Answer (score 0):

DirectX.Capture internally uses DirectShow and builds a filter chain for video capture.  It is just a wrapper around DirectShow.

Unfortunately, you'll need to read up on DirectShow in order to understand how it works.

If you need to process the frames, you'll need to write a *Transform Filter* for DirectShow and insert it into the DirectShow graph between your capture filter and your file writer filter.

If you don't know DirectShow, you won't understand what I am talking about.  Google "DirectShow" and look for some good tutorials.

Comment: Sir can u tell me does direct Show provides YUV streaming?

Comment: @Swati, read up on DirectShow first.  The fact that you need to ask means that you don't know how DirectShow works yet.

Comment: I have read DirectShow from various links but cannot find how to capture yuv data, any help???? I followed the same procedure as in samples but i get AVI file that contains RGB data.if i chnage it to YUV it indicates "Class not Registered"

Comment: OK, your *source* might be returning RGB data.  Check the capture filter of your videocam -- some has a settings dialog that allows you to choose the output format, RGB, YUYV, YUV, or I420 etc.  Make sure you choose YUV.  If your source only supports capturing in RGB (many USB webcams do), then you have to insert a color-space conversion filter to convert RGB into YUV.

Comment: I made a setting for YUV, now i am able to get that and store the contents in an avi file but i found that the audio and video are not in proper sync in the resultant avi file.Can u suggest any idea/reason for this issue. Thank u

Comment: FOr audio sync you'll need some more advanced filters.  Usually for webcams, the video and audio stream go through different filter paths, and they may be *slightly* out of sync.  Depends on how serious it is for you.

Comment: oh sync is of most importance.i have tries chnaging the sampling rate, frame rate etc.. but still cannot get a perfect solution.

Comment: What cam are you using? You really need good hardare support to get good sync.  Software is not going to help you if the data packets already come out unsync.

Comment: I tried on Apple iSight Camera as well as HP Web Cam.I found that when sample rate is decreased fromm 44 KHz then audio is out of sync and sometimes no audio. m trying increasing the sampling rate lets c what happens.

Comment: Beware, many DirectShow filters only support certain sampling rates, with 44K, 22K being most popular.  Any other sampling rates will incur re-sampling which can add latency to your filters path.  By the way, is the audio *faster* or *slower* than the video?

Comment: u r right there are certain sampling rates.I tried changing the values but i found that audio is faster maximum times but some times its slower too.I found that video comes first and audio comes later.

Comment: Are you doing encoding of the audio?  Depends on the CPU required for each stream.  If your video is only being written out raw, then there is no processing needs at all.  Then if you are encoding audio, it will make it slower.  Also, AVI is not a good container for video/audio sync.